# If $a$ is rational and $b$ is irrational, is $ab$ necessarily irrational?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-explanation, rationality-testing

There are some similar questions, but not exactly this one.

**First:**

> As, Zero is a rational number. So, by using the counterexample 
>   $a=0$ and $b=x$ ($x$ being an irrational number) we get $ab = 0$. Thus it is not true that $ab$ necessarily has to be *irrational*.

**Second:**

However, I have learned a technique that I have used to proof similar but slightly different combination ($a$ is rational and $b$ is irrational, is $a+b$ irrational?) of questions.

With this technique (Proof by contradiction):

> Given $a$ is rational and $b$ is irrational. Let, $ab$ be rational.
>
> Suppose, $a= \frac{m}{n}$ and $ab= z =\frac{p}{q}$ , where $m,n,p,q$  are intgers and $n,q \neq 0$
>
> $b=x$ where $x$ is an irrational number.
>
> $$a \cdot b=z$$
>   $$\frac{m}{n} \cdot x=\frac{p}{q}$$
>   $$x=\frac{p}{q} \cdot \frac{n}{m}$$
>   Now, as $p,q,m,n$ are all integers, therefore $x$ is an integer, therefore *rational*, which contradicts our starting assumption that $x$ is an *irrational* number. Therefore, $ab$ is *irrational.*

Now, I think the First conclusion that $ab$ is not necessarily irrational is correct. The second proof is definitely wrong (I think), but I am new to proofs and don't know where it is wrong. What did I miss and not consider in the second approach?

Comment: The last equation of the second proof is invalid if $a = 0$ since then $m = 0$

Comment: Oh, Yes. I got too bogged down on rigid thinking. Then I suppose, if $a \neq 0$, i.e. for all other rational numbers except zero, won't the product of a rational and an irrational number be *irrational* ?

Comment: Moreover, is the first method considered a valid way to prove something?

Comment: To disprove that a statement is true for all values of something, it is perfectly fine to prove that it is not true for a single value. So showing that the statement fails for $a = 0$ is perfectly legitimate.

Comment: Yes, the proof is correct if $a\neq 0$.

Comment: Yes, but it is tne one and only counter example.  So the statement "$a$ rational and $b$ irrational then $ab$ is irrational" may be false.  Then statement " $a$ a non-zero rational and $b$ irrational then $ab$ is irrational" is absolutely true. Or to put it another way: "If $a$ is rational and $b$ is irrational than $ab$ is rational if and only if $a = 0$".

Comment: " The second proof is definitely wrong (I think)"  I wouldn't say it is "definately" wrong.  Id' say it is incomplete.  $\frac mn x= \frac pq$ is correct.  But the conclusion $x = \frac pq \frac nm$ needs to state $x = \frac pq \frac nm$ **IF** $m \ne 0$.  So $ab$ is rational does lead to a contradiction **UNLESS** $a = 0$.  In fact I'd say the proof is definitely *correct* except for one condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $k = m/n$ is rational and $j = p/q\ne 0$ is rational, then $k/j = mq/np$ is rational (and if $j = 0$ then $k/j$ is not irrational; it is simply undefined and meaningless and not a number or anything at all).

So if $ab$ is rational.  And $a$ is rational.  And $a \ne 0$ then than $ab/a = b$ is rational.

So the *only* way. $a$ can rational and $b$  be irrational but somehow $ab $ is rational is if $ab/a$ is not defined.  That only happens if $a$ is zero.  That is the one and only counter example.

As for $a +b$....  Note if $k = m/n$ and $j = p/q$ are rational,  then $k \pm j = \frac {mq \pm pn}{nq}$ is rational.

So if $a$ is rational and $a + b$ is rational, then $(b+a) - a = b$ must also be rational.

So if $a$ is rational and $b$ is irrational there is *no* way possible for $a + b$ to be rational.  There are absolutely no counterexamples.

Answer (score 1):

Posting Kai Rüsch's answer-in-a-comment as an answer:

The last two equations of the second proof are:

$$\frac{m}{n} \cdot x = \frac{p}{q}$$

$$x = \frac{p}{q} \cdot \frac{n}{m}$$

This last equation is invalid if $a = 0$, since then $m = 0$.